# Rails 2.3.9 Sessions Won't Work In Integration Tests Anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

For some reason, my integration tests that are testing my login controller suddenly won't work. Just upgraded to 2.3.9 and been having weird problems. Everything was perfectly fine in 2.3.5 and even 2.3.8! Here's some code that no longer passes:

```
def login_user
  visit login_url
  assert_response :success
  assert_template "new"

  post session_url, :email => "abc@123.com", :password => "secret"
  assert_response :redirect
  follow_redirect!
  assert_response :success
  assert_template "sessions/organizations"

  post organizations_session_url, :id => organizations(:ace).id
  assert_response :redirect
  follow_redirect!
  assert_response :success
  assert_template "mission_control/index"
end
```

When a user logs in their id gets saved to session[:user_id]. When I run the test above it fails after the first follow_redirect!. It appears that session[:user_id] is getting cleared and then asking the user to log in again when they just did. What could be causing my sessions to get cleared? I haven't touched anything. Rails 2.3.5 was fine. Is there a bug in Rails?

Thanks

(Btw, the site runs fine. It's just the integration tests that appear to be messing with my sessions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out. 2.3.10 had the same problem as well.

Instead of using the Rails 2.3.10 gem, I downloaded the latest stable code from their 2.3 branch on github and froze to that. I guess the Rails gems are outdated.

Thanks